# Run script no more than twice a day WITHOUT using cron

Tags: command-line, scripts, 18.04, cron, ubuntu-mate

Can a script be run no more than twice a day WITHOUT using cron ?

8/12/2018 5:46 p.m.

@Ravexina

This is my script using Ravexina recommendation.

```
SCRIPT=$(realpath "$0")
V=$(pstree -sp $$ | grep "($(pgrep -n atd))" -c)

if [ "$V" -ge 1 ];
then
        echo "$SCRIPT" | at "$(date +%H:%M) tomorrow"
fi

Docs_Backups=/media/andy/MAXTOR_SDB1/Ubuntu_Mate_18.04/Documents_Backups/
Scripts_Backups=/media/andy/MAXTOR_SDB1/Ubuntu_Mate_18.04/Script_Backups/
# Backup Documents
gxmessage -fg red -font  'sans 30' -timeout 3  ' BACKING UP FILES FOR UBUNTU_MATE 18.04.3 LTS'
cd ~/Documents
zip -u -q Ubuntu_Documents.zip *.txt *.doc *.rtf *.html *.png *.pdf *.odt *.ods *.odg 
cp Ubuntu_Documents.zip /media/andy/MAXTOR_SDB1/Ubuntu_Mate_18.04/Documents_Backups/Ubuntu_Documents_`date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M"`.zip # date is in year/month/day/hour/minute format
cd /media/andy/MAXTOR_SDB1/Ubuntu_Mate_18.04/Documents_Backups/
# This deletes unneeded date files except newest which are zero bytes
find . -type f -size 0b -delete
sleep 1
touch $( date '+%m-%d-%Y_%I:%M-%p' )
```

When I ran it, nothing happened at 17:41.

```
andy@7_~$ echo $HOME/script.sh | at 17:41
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 4 at Sun Aug 12 17:41:00 2018
```

Comment: I have difficulties to see what you need, just run a script twice a day automatically or prevent a script from running more than twice a day? Please make your question a bit more clear.

Comment: I want to prevent a script from running more than twice.

Comment: I don't get it. Why don't you have cron call the backup script once a day and then optionally call it yourself on demand.

Comment: @fixit7 After the lines from my answer, before your script get started, add `echo hello > $HOME/my-script-output`, then add the script as a `at` job: `echo $HOME/script.sh | at HH:MM` after it got executed check the output of `~/my-script-output`. I want to make sure that the script is getting executed first.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned about `cron` I suppose you are trying to run the script automatically twice a day.

It's better to use `cron`, however you can also use `at` command, lets say my script is located at `$HOME/script.sh` and is executable.

First I need to add these lines in the beginning of my script:

```
SCRIPT=$(realpath "$0")
V=$(pstree -sp $$ | grep "($(pgrep -n atd))" -c)

if [ "$V" -ge 1 ];
then
        echo "$SCRIPT" | at "$(date +%H:%M) tomorrow"
fi
```

The I need to run:

```
echo $HOME/script.sh | at 18:00
echo $HOME/script.sh | at 20:00
```

Now my script will be run at 6PM and 8PM and each time if it has been executed using `at` daemon it will schedule itself to be run tomorrow at the same time.

It's just a funny idea that I wanted to share ;)